# Propagate WTERMSIG exit code from child process on exit

Tags: c, unix, posix

I'm writing a wrapper command that invokes a child process, waits for it to exit, and propagates its exit code. Simple enough.

I want to propagate the exit status of the child process to my own process's exit code *even if the child exited with a signal*. If `WIFSIGNALED(cmdret)` is true for some `int cmdret` that contains the result of a `waitpid(...)` call or similar, I want to set my process exit code the `WTERMSIG(cmdret)` such that `WIFSIGNALED` will return true on the exit code of my own process.

How do I do it? Lets assume I don't want to send my own process a fatal signal that matches that of the child process - if the child exited with `SIGABRT` or `SIGSEGV` I don't want to send an abort or segfault signal to my wrapper.

---

`glibc` defines the relevant macros as

```
/* If WIFEXITED(STATUS), the low-order 8 bits of the status.  */
#define __WEXITSTATUS(status)   (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)

/* If WIFSIGNALED(STATUS), the terminating signal.  */
#define __WTERMSIG(status)      ((status) & 0x7f)

/* If WIFSTOPPED(STATUS), the signal that stopped the child.  */
#define __WSTOPSIG(status)      __WEXITSTATUS(status)

/* Nonzero if STATUS indicates normal termination.  */
#define __WIFEXITED(status)     (__WTERMSIG(status) == 0)

/* Nonzero if STATUS indicates termination by a signal.  */
#define __WIFSIGNALED(status) \
  (((signed char) (((status) & 0x7f) + 1) >> 1) > 0)
```

and `exit(...)` docs say:

> The  `exit()` function causes normal process termination and the least significant byte of `status` (i.e., `status & 0xFF`) is returned to the parent (see `wait(2)`).

Similarly `_exit(...)` returns `status & 0xFF`, and the return value from `main` uses the low 8 bits for normal exit codes.

The [shell convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) is to use exit codes less than 125 for the child process exit, 126 as "found but not executable", 127 as "not found", and 128+N as "exited with signal N". That works, but requires the caller to be aware of whether they're invoking the process via an intermediate shell or not to interpret the exit code correctly.

This makes it impossible to differentiate between processes that themselves exited with codes greater than 125 and a signal exit or failure of the wrapper or shell. It could break commands that invoke the wrapped command if they use test macros like `WIFEXITED`, `WTERMSIG` etc on the return code of the original command. The wrapper will appear to have exited normally even if the child exited on a signal.

I want my wrapper to be completely transparent to the invoker, so calling `WEXITSIG(ret)` on my wrapper's return code will return the signal if the wrapped process in turn exited with a signal.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: I don't think unix kernels will let you fake signal death without actually going through signal death. Why are you trying to avoid it? Coredumps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replicate the wait status of a child in the parent,
then if `WIFEXITED(ws)` returns true, you can`_exit(WEXITSTATUS(ws))` and if `WIFSIGNALED(ws)` returns true, you can do `signal(WTERMSIG(ws),SIG_DFL); raise(WTERMSIG(ws));` (i.e., raise the same signal after resetting it to its default disposition so that raising it surely will kill the process).

I don't think Unix kernels will let you fake signal death without actually going through signal death. If you're trying to avoid it to prevent coredumps, then you could possibly use platform-specific solutions to disable coredumps just for your wrapper process. E.g., on Linux, you can call `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE,0);`.

Comment: Yeah, I alluded to self-signalling. The problem with this is that there can be a variety of externally visible behaviour in response to signal exits that I don't really want to trigger on my wrapper; e.g. if I `raise(SIGSEGV)` the kernel's global coredump handler is likely to run on my wrapper. I guess it's fundamentally not solve-able, because I want to exit identically to the called child as far as the caller is concerned but *not* exit identically to the called child process as far as the kernel or other observers are concerned. Which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @CraigRinger Well, as I said in my comment simultaneously to yours, I don't think Unix kernels will let you fake signal death without actually going through actual signal death. A workaround for the coredump problem might be platform-specifically disabling coredumps just for the wrapper process (e.g., `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE,0);` on Linux).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. It's a frustrating limitation but an unsurprising one.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to propagate the exit status of the child process to my own process's exit code even if the child exited with a signal. If WIFSIGNALED(cmdret) is true for some int cmdret that contains the result of a waitpid(...) call or similar, I want to set my process exit code the WTERMSIG(cmdret) such that WIFSIGNALED will return true on the exit code of my own process.

You cannot.  You can only propagate the exit code for a process that did an `exit(2)` call.  The reason is simple.  The result code you receive from the `wait(2)` call is generated by the kernel.  It fills the exit code with the exit code you provide to the `exit(2)` system call, but you cannot force the other bits (the exit code is only the least significant 8 bits of the value) are filled by the kernel, and you cannot control what to put in them.  This would fake the `wait(2)` system call, as a malicious (or broken) program could put incorrect information about a process that exited correctly but informed about receiving a signal or dumping a core image. The exit code is the only information that is user provided, so you can do with it whatever you like (like propagating or even cheating it)  This will not affect of the final status (of course you cannot pass an exit code if you die from an interruption)